# Data from sql database for Android App

Tags: android, sql

I am building a fun facts app for a project and I want to access a sql database. The sql database has 1500 rows, so I want to get a random number and based on that number, display the fact on the corresponding row. I already have the number I just need a way to get the data from that specific row from the database. Plz help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve a record from an sql server by row number unless it is a field in the database.  There is no concept of row numbers in sql.

You can retrieve a random record by the following (different sql servers may be slightly different):

```
select * from table order by random() limit 1;
```

As an alternative, create a row number field, populate it and select using that.

Comment: How would I create a rown number field and populate it? Also how would I ask for data from Java (Android Studio). I haven't done this before so any help would be great.

Comment: Answers to both of those questions depends on what SQL server you're using,  Have you looked for any tutorials for android and the database you intend to work with?